# Javascript: How convert array of objects to object with sorted unique arrays?

Tags: javascript

Have data that has this kind of structure:

```
$input = [ { animal: 'cat', name: 'Rocky', value: 1 },
           { animal: 'cat', name: 'Spot',  value: 2 },
           { animal: 'dog', name: 'Spot',  value: 3 } ];
```

Need fastest possible method for converting to this format:

```
$output = { animal: [ 'cat', 'dog' ],
            name: [ 'Rocky', 'Spot' ],
            value: [ 1, 2, 3 ] };
```

The output should have keys equal to each of the keys in each object from the input. And the output values should be arrays with the sorted unique values.  I found a few ways to do it using nested loops, but slower than I would like.  With 30,000 elements to the input array with 8 keys for each of the objects, the best I have been able to do is 300ms in Chrome.  Would like to get down to 100ms.  Is there any faster method using a map or reduce?

Comment: Why not post what you currently have? It seems like you would be as simple as pushing values onto an array, and then deduping / sorting at the end.

Comment: It's always space-time tradeoffs and efficiency. You could trade space for time.

Comment: Remember that $ is not JavaScript - that's a PHP variable. Nested loops is the best you're going to get on that - it's all you have there. Why do you want to change the structure that way? The input seems far more sensible and usable.

Comment: @Bradley: Incorrect. `$something` is a valid variable name in Javascript. How do you think jQuery works?

Comment: Nested loops are not the best he could get on that. As I said he could trade space for time and do that in a single loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
$input = [ { animal: 'cat', name: 'Rocky', value: 1 },
           { animal: 'cat', name: 'Spot',  value: 2 },
           { animal: 'dog', name: 'Spot',  value: 3 } ];

$output = {animal:{},name:{},value:{}};

$input.forEach(function(v,i) { 
    $output.animal[v.animal] = 1;
    $output.name[v.name] = 1;
    $output.value[v.value] = 1;
});

$output.animal = Object.keys($output.animal);
$output.name = Object.keys($output.name);
$output.value = Object.keys($output.value);
```

It prevents having to test each Array every time. You can performance compare to see if it helps.

***live example:*** http://jsfiddle.net/TJVtj/1/

---

If you don't want to hardcode the keys, you can make the solution generic.

```
var keys = Object.keys($input[0]),
    $output = {};

keys.forEach(function(v) {
    $output[v] = {};
});

$input.forEach(function(v) {
    keys.forEach(function(vv) {
        $output[vv][v[vv]] = 1;
    });
});

keys.forEach(function(v) {
    $output[v] = Object.keys($output[v]);
});
```

***live example:*** http://jsfiddle.net/TJVtj/2/

*Warning. All the values will be strings since they're fetched as object keys.*

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way for modern browsers:

```
$input.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    acc[k] = (acc[k] || []).concat(obj[k])
  })
  return acc
},{})
```

Comment: This is the functional "underscore-y" way of doing it! This should be the Top Answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Above function is used to check duplicates

```
$output={};
for(i=0; i< $input.length; i++)
{
    if(!$output.animal) $output.animal=[];
    if(!$output.name) $output.name=[];
    if(!$output.value) $output.value=[];
    var ani=$input[i];
    if(ani.animal && !inArray(ani.animal, $output.animal)) $output.animal.push(ani.animal);
    if(ani.name && !inArray(ani.name, $output.name)) $output.name.push(ani.name);
    if(ani.value) $output.value.push(ani.value);
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/GrWm7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

// If you don't know the objects all have the same keys you need to look at each one-

```
var output= {},
input= [{
    animal:'cat', name:'Rocky', value:1
},{
    animal:'cat', name:'Spot', value:2
},{
    animal:'dog', name:'Spot', value:3
}];
input.forEach(function(itm){
    for(var p in itm){
        if(itm.hasOwnProperty(p)){
            if(!output[p]) output[p]= [];
            if(output[p].indexOf(itm[p])== -1) output[p].push(itm[p]);
        }
    }
});

Run.expose(output)// nonstandard object to string method

// returned value: (String)
{
    animal:[
        'cat',
        'dog'
    ],
    name:[
        'Rocky',
        'Spot'
    ],
    value:[
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), it's magnificent with this kind of tasks)